# Auto script generate for add two numbers does not working properly

Tags: javascript

Expected Result : User should be able to get the summation of the two numbers
Actual result : User cannot get the summation of the two numbers correctly. Every time Firstly input value show as the summation.

How can I solve this. This is my JavaScript file.

```
public add_two_numbers(): string {
    var first = prompt('First Field');
    first = this.removeNonAlphaNumric(first)
    var second = prompt('Second Field');
    second = this.removeNonAlphaNumric(second)
    var result = prompt('Result Field');
    result = this.removeNonAlphaNumric(result)
    if (first == null || first.length < 1) return ''
    if (second == null || second.length < 1) return ''
    if (result == null || result.length < 1) return ''

    return '\n//Add Two Numbers\n\
    var e1 = document.getElementById("'+first+'");\n\
    if(e1){\n\
      e1.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);\n\
    }\n\
    \n\
    var e2 = document.getElementById("'+second+'");\n\
    if(e2){\n\
      e2.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);\n\
    }\n\
    \n\
    function myFunction() {\n\
      var R = document.getElementById("'+result+'");\n\
      var V1 = document.getElementById("'+first+'");\n\
      var V2 = document.getElementById("'+second+'");\n\
    \n\
      R.value = V1.value + V2.value;\n\
    }'

}
```

[image: CHECK THIS]

Comment: Is this angular project?

Comment: create jsfiddle including html and javascript code.

Comment: Try `change` event instead of `click`

Comment: Hi @User863 Its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you add the two variables it is concating e1 and e2 as it taking them as String. You can typecast them to numbers while adding i.e.

```
R.value = Number(V1.value) + Number(V2.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `keyup` event instead of click.

```js
    var e1 = document.getElementById("noone");
    if(e1){
      e1.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction, false);
    }

    var e2 = document.getElementById("notwo");
    if(e2){
      e2.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction, false);
    }

    function myFunction() {
      var R = document.getElementById("sum");
      var V1 = document.getElementById("noone");
      var V2 = document.getElementById("notwo");

      R.value = parseInt(V1.value) + parseInt(V2.value);
      if(isNaN(R.value)){
        R.value = "";
      }
    }
```

```html
<input id='noone' type="text" placeholder="First integer"/><br/>
<input id='notwo' type="text" placeholder="Second Integer"/><br/>
<input id='sum' placeholder="Sum"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var sum = 0;
$(document).on('keyup','#noone', function(){

    var e1 = $('#noone').val();
    var e2 = $('#notwo').val();
    if (e2) {

    sum = (parseFloat(e1)+parseFloat(e2));
    }else{
    sum =e1;
    }
    $('#sum').val(sum);
});

$(document).on('keyup','#notwo', function(){

    var e1 = $('#noone').val();
    var e2 = $('#notwo').val();
    if (e1 && e2) {

    sum = (parseFloat(e1)+parseFloat(e2));
    }
    else if (e2) {

    sum = e2;
    }else{
    sum =  e1;
    }
    $('#sum').val(sum);
});
```